# Way to solve transcendental inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

Rookie question but is there a way to solve a simple $2^x \le x^8$ in any way without using a graphical method or an approximation technique?

Comment: The solution is $$\frac{\log x}{x}\geq\frac{\log 2}{8}$$  If you need an explicit upper bound for $x$ you'll have to use numerical methods.

Comment: @saulspatz It seems to me that you are neglecting the case $x<0$.

Comment: @Gae.S. You're right.  I was thinking $x\geq0$.  Don't know why.

Comment: Hi XDead, Clearly you have many values $x_1\gt0$ and $x_2\lt0$  such that $x^8\gt 2^x$ for all $x\gt x_1$ and $x\lt x_2$. The corresponding two critic values (minimum $x_1$ and maximum $x_2$), by the concavity of the curves are given by the equation $2^x=x^8$. Unfortunately this is a trascendental equation and you don't have elementary way to solve it without numerical approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you need to solve $2^x = x^8$.
Put $y = - \frac18 (\log 2) x$.  Then it becomes
$$ y e^{y} = \pm z := \pm \tfrac18 \log 2 .$$
This is solved by the Lambert $W$-function.  There are three real answers: $W_0(z)$, $W_0(-z)$ and $W_{-1}(-z)$.  Thus your problem is solved by
$$ -\frac 8{\log 2} W_0(z) \le x \le -\frac 8{\log 2} W_0(-z) \text{ or } x \ge -\frac 8{\log 2} W_{-1}(-z) .$$
You have admittedly merely reduced the problem to that of calculating the $W$ function.  But in principle. this is no different than calculating the exponential or trigonometric functions.